# Linking PDFs on a hard drive on a web page

Tags: .net

I'm running a .Net website.  The docroot is on the C: drive and the system generates PDFs to a folder on the E: drive. I want to have links to the PDFs on my website. The E: drive isn't an HTTP drive though, it's just a Windows drive.

1. Is there a simple way to link to the PDFs, or do I have to move them all to the docroot in C:?
2. Also, I need to keep the E: drive and folders secure from hackers.

I'm looking for a simple, safe solution.

Update: I found this solution.  I pass in the contract ID.  The PDFs' names are based on the contract IDs. This code opens the PDF in my browser.

```
strPDF0="S" & getFormatwith0(cint(ContractID),3) & ".PDF"
strPDF="E:\FTProot\docs\" & strPDF0
Set FSOobj = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if FSOobj.FileExists(strPDF) Then 
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
'Set file name
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & strPDF0

Set oFileStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oFileStream.Open
oFileStream.Type = 1 'Binary
oFileStream.LoadFromFile strPDF

Response.BinaryWrite(oFileStream.Read)

oFileStream.Close
Set oFileStream= Nothing
Else
Response.Write "Contract does not exist"
End if 
Set FSOobj = Nothing
```

Comment: Are we talking development here? Can you modify the source code? .NET isn't a *language*.

Comment: Why did you vote me down?  And one can say a .Net website just like one can say a Drupal website or a LAMP website.   Lighten up.   For others who come to this site for help, I'm editing the text with the answer I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send a file as a link, since user could not access `e:\myfolder\`

However, you can write a file as response like the following. Please make sure you set appropiate read access to `e:\myfolder\`

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf");
response.WriteFile("e:\myfolder\file.pdf");
response.End();
```

Comment: This answer is very close to the one I found. Thanks.